# Taking data from a line of another file

Tags: java, arrays, file

i'm creating a simple rpg game and i need to get information from one file and store it in my variables to be able to make the user save/modify items in the game easily, i can read my files but i do not know how to get the name and the numbers inside this lables:

```
itemName:("Steel Sword"),itemStats(2,0,0);
```

i need to get "Steel Sword" in a String and the numbers to the other variables...

maybe you could tell me also how to connect the name to the stats, i don't have really a good way to do it.

i tried to use indexOf to get the start and end of the string but i need to figure out the separators on the stats and maybe there's a more reliable way to do this...

Comment: There are ways to parse that file format, but it would be significantly easier to use a more common format such as JSON where many libraries already exist to parse it for you. Is using an alternative file format an option for you?

Comment: I also think that JSON would be better as @hopperelec mentioned. Or XML format.

Comment: It is a bit strange. Why after `itemName` there is a colon `:`, but after `itemStats` there isn't?

Comment: it's not the file the problem it's taking the data, i can acess and read it, i just don't know how to make te code get the name and stats

Comment: 'make the code get the name and stats' so you're looking to read properties from text, which is known as parsing. Parsing custom file formats (I don't recognise this file format so I'm assuming it's custom) can be quite difficult, but there are alternative formats, such as what I and Christoph suggested, where the code to parse it has already been written for you

Comment: the format is just a .txt so the user can create a new item using the same "formula". i didn't know it was called parsing, now i may search better for how to do it... ah and sorry for my bad english, i'm not a native speaker.

Comment: .txt is just a file extension which doesn't necessarily indicate whether the contents are formatted in a specific way. JSON is actually pretty similar to your "formula" and I think it is formatted in a way which would actually be easier for a user to make changes to, partly because it is slightly more flexible (for example, both speech marks and apostrophes work for strings + most whitespace and new lines are ignored so can be used for formatting to make it more readable). Here is what your file would look like in JSON format: {"itemName": "Steel Sword", "itemStats": [2,0,0]}

Comment: great i just need to parse now right? i'm searchin but can't understand much, so i'm trying diffrent methods tomorrow. thanks

Comment: If you can’t change the file format to JSON or CSV or anything a pre-defined parser, you could go for regular expressions using java.util.regex.Pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code makes use of an **Item** class so that instances of Items can be instantiated since you must have more than one Item within the file. A List Interface (`List<Item>`) will hold instances of **Item** once the file is read. Read comments in code:

**The Item class:**

```
public class Item {
    
    private String itemName;    // Item Name  
    // For lack of better member variable names since none were supplied in post.
    private int manna = 0;      // Stat 1
    private int banna = 0;      // Stat 2
    private int hanna = 0;      // Stat 3

    
    public Item() { }

    public Item(String itemName, int manna, int banna, int hanna) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.manna = manna;
        this.banna = banna;
        this.hanna = hanna;
    }

    // Getters & Setters
    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

    public int getManna() {
        return manna;
    }

    public void setManna(int manna) {
        this.manna = manna;
    }

    public int getBanna() {
        return banna;
    }

    public void setBanna(int banna) {
        this.banna = banna;
    }

    public int getHanna() {
        return hanna;
    }

    public void setHanna(int hanna) {    
        this.hanna = hanna;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return itemName + ", " + manna + ", " + banna + ", " + hanna;
    }
}
```

**The File Reader/Parser (*getItemsFromFile()*) code:**

```
public void getItemsFromFile(String filePath) throws IOException {
    itemsList = new ArrayList<>();  // Initialize itemsList

    // Read file...
    // 'Try With Resources' used here to Auot-Close reader and free resources:
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = line.trim();  // Remove leading/trailing whitespaces (if any);
            // Skip blank lines (if any).
            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            
            // Get Items (only) ...
            if (line.startsWith("itemName:")) {
                // Parse the Item line...
                String[] parts = line.split("itemStats");
                String name = parts[0].substring(parts[0].indexOf("(\"") + 2, parts[0].indexOf("\")"));
                parts[1] = parts[1].replaceAll("[^0-9,]", "");
                String[] statValues = parts[1].split(",");
                int m = Integer.parseInt(statValues[0]);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(statValues[1]);
                int h = Integer.parseInt(statValues[2]);
                itemsList.add(new Item(name, m, b, h)); // Add Item instance to List.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**How you might use the above *getItemsFromFile()* method:**

```
// Declare as Class member
List<Item> itemsList;  

// In some class method...
try {
    // Do as the method name states (use the proper file path):
    getItemsFromFile("GameConfig.txt");
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    /* Do what you want with the exception (if there is one).
       Whatever you do, don't leave this blank.          */
    System.err.println(ex);
}
    
//Display Items contained within the itemsList List:
for (Item items : itemsList) {
    /* Using the Item class toString() method:  */
    System.out.println(items.toString());
         
    /* Example of retrieving each object within an Item instance:
       using Item class Getter methods:                     */
    System.out.println("Item Name:  " + items.getItemName());  // String
    System.out.println("The Manna:  " + items.getManna());     // int
    System.out.println("The Banna:  " + items.getBanna());     // int
    System.out.println("The Hanna:  " + items.getHanna());     // int
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code. i have only two questions: if i have more items in the json will it read all of them? and how can i select 1 of those items from the list? thanks again

Comment: 1) Yes, as long as they are all in the same format. 2) Iterate through the collected List of `Item` (the `itemList` List) as was done to display them to console except you would have an `if` statement within the loop which makes use of the **Item** class getter methods: `int manna, banna, hanna; for (Item items : itemsList) { if (items.getItemName().equalsIgnoreCase("steel sword")) { manna = items.getManna(); banna = items.getBanna(); hanna = items.getHanna(); break; } System.out.println("Stats for Steel Sword: -> " + manna + ", " + banna + ", " + hanna);`

Comment: Thanks a lot now i'll be searching for how to sort a matix like a maze.. If you know a question that already answers that could you send it here?

Comment: If you have found that this (or another) answer was helpful towards your particular problem then please [accept that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is to 'parse' your text file. Parsing is where you convert arbitrary data (usually human-readable text) into data your computer program can understand. Parsing custom formats (which I assume this is since I don't seem to recognise it) can be quite difficult, so you may want to consider using a more popular format such as JSON which already has plenty of libraries to parse it for you. JSON is actually pretty similar to the format you're using already, so it shouldn't be too difficult to make the switch! The data you provided could look like this in the JSON format (some minor changes can be made, for example the whitespace between values can be removed):

```
{"itemName": "Steel Sword", "itemStats": [2,0,0]}
```